# Как завершить поток спустя 5 секунд

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

```
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::thread ft(SendRecv);
}

void SendRecv(){
  while (true);
}
```

Знаю, написан не очень полезный код...
Но мне нужно понять, как завершить поток, **если он сам не завершился** через 5 секунд

Comment: Средствами операционной системы, например. Но лучше насильственно поток не убивать - это таки насилие над ресурсами, например, над прерванной логикой... Лучше бы переписать его так, чтобы он завершился сам.

Comment: @Harry это не возможно сделать. Т.к. y меня ZMQ иногда зависает. Для того и пилю, как экстренный рубильник

Comment: Ну, тогда я бы (с пониманием всех проблем) использовал `native_handle()` и API операционной системы...

Comment: @Harry я НЕ использую API операционной системы

Comment: @Harry можно ли обойтись без этого?

Comment: Запросто - завершить программу. Просто убить объект потока нельзя - "*If *this has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), std::terminate() is called.*" ([отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread)). Функция для убиения потока нет. Так что еще раз советую - перепишите поток так, чтоб он завершился сам...

Comment: @Harry очень жаль. Надеюсь, кто-то придумает все же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class stoppable {
public:
    stoppable()
        : m_termination_signal()
        , m_future(m_termination_signal.get_future())
    {}

    stoppable(stoppable&& obj) noexcept
        : m_termination_signal(std::move(obj.m_termination_signal))
        , m_future(std::move(obj.m_future))
    {}

    stoppable& operator=(stoppable&& obj) noexcept {
        if (this != &obj) {
            m_termination_signal = std::move(obj.m_termination_signal);
            m_future = std::move(obj.m_future);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    virtual void run() = 0;

    bool stopping() {
        if (m_future.wait_for(1ms) == std::future_status::timeout)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    void stop() {
        m_termination_signal.set_value();
    }

protected:
    std::promise<void> m_termination_signal;
    std::future<void>  m_future;
};

class task: public stoppable
{
public:
    void run() override {
        while (not stopping())
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
};

int main() {
    task task;
    std::thread th {[&]() { task.run(); }};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    task.stop();
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

[Запустить пример в wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ES9q1ixANoTMnSOh)